# Parallel watch Vs watch && Autos vs Locals in visual studio

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging, watch

1.What's difference between Parallel Watch & Watch and the significance of both?

2.What's difference between Autos & Locals and the significance of both?

Comment: Parallel Watch is for debugging multithread code.
"In the Parallel Watch window, you can simultaneously display the values that one expression holds on multiple threads."
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh418499.aspx

Answer (score 9):

Locals:
Locals windows automatically displays the list of variables and it’s values within the scope of current methods.

Autos :
These variables are also automatically detect by the Visual Studio debugger during the debugging. Visual Studio determines which objects or variables are important for the current code statement and based on that, it lists down the “Autos” variable.  Generally this shows the object in  current statement and the previous statement  with in that current scope.

Watch :
You can manually set which data needs to be displayed, can be typed in or dropped in

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/121623/Tips-you-should-know-about-Watch-Window-While-d

http://dailydotnettips.com/2016/01/10/difference-between-autos-and-locals-window-in-visual-studio/